# Topology Library for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, geospatial, topology

I need to do some geographic topology teting (intersection, contains, etc.) for a project I'm working on. I would like to use a Node.js server and keep the data in a JSON-esque format as much as possible, meaning I would like to use a topology library that is written in JavaScript. I've found one, [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts), but it relies on OpenLayers and I only has one project using it at the moment. Does anyone have any experience with this library or any other topology libraries? Also, if this is a terrible idea please let me know and I'll move to a Java server with the JTS topology suite.

Comment: Since release 0.11, JSTS no longer has a hard dependency on OpenLayers.

Comment: Well that's good. Have you used it at all? I haven't had time to mess with it since posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the open source javascript library `GeoScript` - it has basic geometric functions like intersection and union - see link below.

http://geoscript.org/examples/geom/index.html#examples-geom

NOTE : does not seem to include a `contains` function, and also seems to operate on the WellKnownText data representation, not JSON.

Comment: No but I will. Thanks for the link.